# update devuelve solo el dato actualizado

Tags: nodejs

Quiero actualizar los datos por medio de una petición al API pero solo obtengo el dato que actualice, *es un ambiente local.. no hay conexión con BD*.

**Controlador**

```
exports.bicicleta_update = function(req,res){
var bici = Bicicleta.finById(req.params.id);
bici.id = req.body.id;
bici.color = req.body.color;
bici.modelo = req.body.modelo;
bici.ubicacion = [req.body.latitud, req.body.longitud];

res.status(200).json({
    bicicleta : bici
 })
}
```

**Ruta**

```
router.put('/:id/update',bicicletaController.bicicleta_update);
```

**Respuesta**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Peticion GET

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Quieres actualizar un dato sin conexión a la BD? ¿De dónde obtienes este dato? Por lo que veo de tu código ¿Quieres recibir un dato del usuario y complementarlo con datos del request del mismo para luego devolverle como respuesta el mismo elemnteto con la información que adjuntaste del request inicial? No comprendo exactamente que quieres hacer

Comment: Exacto, como le estas mandando los datos ?? color, modelo, ubicación ??

Comment: si, actualizar datos que estan en un objeto creado por mi

Comment: ¿Dónde está ese objeto? Cuando haces referencia a por ejemplo `req.body.modelo` estás haciendo referencia al request del usuario... ¿Los datos también los tiene el usuario? Tu request (según lo que deduzco por el screenshot de postman)  solo tiene la propiedad `color` con el valor `amarillo`

Comment: ahh okay, si estan en un vista formulario por eso viene de req.body

Comment: Pero tu `req.body` según lo que veo en tu postman es solo `{"color":"amarillo"}`

Comment: si hago la peticion get al API trae todos los datos que tengo en el objeto obviamente

Comment: ahi puse una imagen de lo que seria req.body